# how to use Spinner in Custom Diolog Box?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want use `Spinner` in Custom `Dialog Box`. i use `activity` show as `Dialog Box`, inside activity use `Spinner`. but when convert Activity to Dialog Box Spinner's items not shown !!

**My XML Code :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/add_sms_dialog_background"
    tools:context="com.tellfa.smsbox.addSMS_Page">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addSMS_cover_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_sms_dialog_coverlayout">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/addSMS_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/all_users_avatar"
            app:border_color="@color/activity_bg_color"
            app:border_width="2dp" />

        <com.tellfa.smsbox.components.tellfa_TextView
            android:id="@+id/addSMS_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addSMS_profile_image"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="@color/activity_bg_color"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addSMS_close_image"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:src="@drawable/close_dialog" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/addSMS_smsInfo_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addSMS_cover_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp">

        <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
            style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner.Light"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_no_arrow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="128dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave.Light"
            app:rd_enable="true"
            app:spn_labelEnable="true"
            app:spn_label="Spinner without arrow"
            app:spn_arrowSize="0dp"
            app:spn_popupItemAnimation="@anim/abc_fade_in"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my Java code :**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main_Page.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_sms);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);

                ImageView closeDialog_image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addSMS_close_image);
                closeDialog_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

i use this library for **Spinner** : [Click to see](https://github.com/rey5137/material/wiki/Spinner)

how to fix it?

Comment: Have you provided an adapter which contains all the item of the spinner

Comment: @L-X, tnx but how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Provide an adapter for spinner , without it no item will be shown provide this code in your dialog

```
String[] items ={"item 1","item 2","item 3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner spin=(Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_no_arrow);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: tnx, i'm insert this code to Dialog code, but show FC error when start application

Comment: Try now , Updated the code , and if still you get error just let me know